# SQL vb.net search term count or rank

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to be able to search a table for the use of a phrase or keyword/term and have the query return the results and also count the number of times the term is used in each row, not necessarily column though. I modified my query, trying from manager studio, to see where the errors are. I am getting an error near ','. but can't determine why. Thanks for the help.

```
SELECT (KEY_TBL.[KEY], FT_TBL.title, FT_TBL.url, KEY_TBL.rank, FT_TBL.html) 
FROM content AS FT_TBL INNER JOIN FREETEXTABLE (content, html, 'income tax', 25) 
AS KEY_TBL ON FT_TBL.id = KEY_TBL.[KEY] ORDER BY KEY_TBL.Rank DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the FREETEXTTABLE function, rather than FREETEXT - this will return a rank for relevance of the matches

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879245

Try this

```
SELECT 
    KEY_TBL.[KEY], FT_TBL.title, FT_TBL.url, KEY_TBL.rank, FT_TBL.html
FROM content AS FT_TBL 
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE (content, html, 'income tax', 25)  AS KEY_TBL 
    ON FT_TBL.id = KEY_TBL.[KEY] 
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.Rank DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. I have modified the sql query but am getting an error near a comma, but not sure why...